# Validate object to RESTeasy method using specific validation group

Tags: resteasy, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I am attempting to validate the input to a REST method using one or more specific validation groups, but so far I have been unable to figure out how to properly do it. I am using RESTeasy 3.X with Hibernate Validator 5.X.

I know that prior to the Bean Validation 1.1 spec, a RESTeasy method could be annotated with something like:

```
 @ValidateRequest(groups=MyGroup.class)
```

However, this functionality no longer exists in Hibernate Validator 5.X.

Suppose I have an entity like:

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "example_table")
 @XmlRootElement
 public class ExampleEntity implements Mappable, Serializable
 {
     // ...

     @Column(name = "title")
     @NotEmpty(groups = Default.class, ExampleEntityGroup.class)
     @Size(max = 255)
     private String title;

     @Column(name = "description")
     @NotEmpty(groups = Default.class)
     @Size(max = 255)
     private String description;

     // ...
 }
```

Now I'd like to define a REST PUT method to update this entity, and I'd like the "description" field to allow an empty value. For this to happen I'd like to validate the entity using the `ExampleEntityGroup` group that I've defined (whereas the `Default` group would be used to validate POST requests that create new objects).

Right now my update method interface looks something like:

```
 @Path("{id}")
 @PUT
 @Consumes(...)
 @Produces(...)
 ExampleEntity update(@PathParam("id"), ExampleEntity exampleEntity);
```

However, with this as written, it will always validate `exampleEntity` using the `Default` validation group. What would I do to force the `update()` method to use the other validation group?

The only documentation I could find that seems close to this is an [example from the Bean Validation spec that uses an interceptor](http://beanvalidation.org/1.1/spec/#validationapi-validatorapi-methodlevelvalidationmethods). Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RestEasy 3 with Bean Validation 1.1 will automatically validate constrained resource methods, i.e. it suffices to place a constraint annotation to a resource method parameter or return value and it will be validated. There is no way to validate a specific group, it will always be the default group. You could try and open a [feature request](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RESTEASY) for the RestEasy project for this.